# Groovy Creating Json from variable

Tags: json, groovy

Process:
get the response text (JSON) from API [get method] and create a new JSON runtime with the response-text

Step1 :
get the response-text

```
def response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Get form', [('masterId') : '12']))
def responseText = response.getResponseText()
```

Step2
Stored the response in map

```
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(responseText)
```

Step3
Creating a JSON using groovy [JsonBuilder]

```
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
jsonBuilder.entity(
    clientid: '2',
    referenceno: '18',
    form: 'AIA-sb0059',
    masterinfo:'$parsedJson.values()',
    userid: '14',
    username: 'abc@xyz.com',
)
```

Problem

`masterinfo` section I have passed the map variable `$parsedJson.values()` it's not binding the map value, when I print this its looks below format

```
 "entity": {
        "clientid": "2",
        "referenceno": "18",
        "form": "AIA-sb0059",
        "masterinfo": "$parsedJson.values()",
        "userid": "14",
        "username": "abc@xyz.com"
    }
```

how can we set the value from variable?

Comment: Problem solved : masterInfo:"${parsedJson.values()}"  curly braces missing

Comment: Why do you want to use a java toString serialized string in your JSON?